# VBA Linear Regression Analysis with Button

Tags: vba, button, linear-regression, data-analysis, developer-tools

I am running a fairly large macro that includes running a linear regression analysis from the Analysis Toolpak.

When I run it through the separate VB window, it runs just fine, but after creating a form control button and assigning the same macro to it, it does not work.

The linear regression analysis creates a new page as desired:
[image: new page]

But it replaces the analyzed data with the cell formatting from the analysis:
[image: cell formatting]

Can anybody help me to make the button run the sub properly?

This is the code that I used to call the linear regression:

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range(loc1(1), loc1(2)), _
    ActiveSheet.Range(loc1(3), loc1(4)), False, True, 99, "Regression " & tabname, True, _
    True, True, True, , False
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but add a Reference to The Analysis Toolpack in your VBA project by selecting your project in the VBA editor, then go to tools -> add reference, then check 'atpvbaen.xls'  After that you can call Regress without having to use Application.Run  If you need more help, what is loc1?

Comment: After doing that, it still has the same issue.
loc1 is output from a function that determines the cell references for the starting and ending cell references for the data that is to be regressed.  I double checked that and it is giving the right output.

Comment: After looking at the output of the regression function, I noticed that all of the output is the same for when I run it pressing the button as when I run it otherwise except for the Residual Output.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this excellent VBA code from Chad Rankin:

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=9070

- This code allows you to perform a multiple linear regression analysis on variables that are not contiguous on the spreadsheet - vars on columns side-by-side.
- it's extremely fast, since the author took the time to carefully choose the matrix multiplication formulas that do not consume computer time
- the website freevbcode.com has proved to be a reliable source of curated VB code to me in the past

Quoted from the website:

> Version Compatibility: Visual Basic 6
>
> More information:
>   This code performs a multiple linear regression analysis by programming the worksheet using R1C1 references and VBA. Analysis data are input through a userform and the resultant model is constructed on a new worksheet with all applicable worksheet functions included. Since the data are not mean centered or standardized, numerical inaccuracy may result where the data are significantly ill-conditioned.
>
> INSTRUCTIONS: Click the link below to download the code. Select 'Save' from the IE popup dialog. Once downloaded, open the .zip file from your local drive using WinZip or a comparable program to view the contents.